# How to force Plot[..] to show the x-axis?

Tags: plotting

When I use

```
Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

the plot shows the y-range between 1 and 2.5:

[image: Plot of first input]

I would like to tell Mathematica that I want to see the x-axis (i.e. y=0) in my plot. One idea I had is to use

```
Plot[{Exp[x],0}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

which yields my desired result, but has an extra colored line at y=0:

[image: Plot of second input]

How can I achieve the result of my second input without having two lines in my plot?

Comment: try `Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: Amazing, that did it!